# SignalR C# Client not receiving data when executed in unit test (SpecFlow)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signalr, specflow

I'm trying to do an end-to-end testing of an application using SpecFlow. The system under test is some kind of ticketing system; a new ticket can (only) be created by calling a Web API, and when a new ticket has been created, a notification is sent using SignalR. The SpecFlow scenario looks like

```
@Notifications
Scenario: A notification is sent when a new ticket has been created
    Given I am receiving change notifications when a new ticket has been created
    When I create a new ticket
    Then the new ticket is sent by a push notification
```

which maps to the following methods:

```
//Step 1
[Given(@"I am receiving change notifications when a new ticket has been created")]
public async Task GivenIAmReceivingChangeNotificationsWhenANewTicketHasBeenCreated()
{    
    var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:5001/ws/v1/ticket")
    .AddJsonProtocol(o => o.PayloadSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()))
    .ConfigureLogging(x =>
    {
        //Custom ILogger which does nothing but enables me to set breakpoints
        x.AddProvider(new DoNothingLoggerProvider());
    })
    .Build();

    await connection.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    connection.On<TicketDetails>("NewTicketRegistered", ticket =>
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException("Never reached")
    });
}

//Step 2
[When(@"I create a new ticket")]
public async Task WhenICreateANewTicket()
{        
    var ticketId = await MyApiClient.TicketsPostAsync(new NewTicket(), CancellationToken.None);
    ticketId.Should().NotBe(default(Guid));
}

//Step 3
[Then(@"the new ticket is sent by a push notification")]
public async Task ThenTheNewTicketIsSentByAPushNotification()
{   
   await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Here, `TicketDetails` and `MyApiClient` are generated from OpenAPI.

My problem is that the callback listed in `connection.On<TicketDetails>` is never invoked, SpecFlow will after step 2 (API is called to create a new ticket) go on to step 3 where it waits for 5 sec before the test scenario completes. During these 5 seconds, the notification from SignalR has been sent. I have verified that by created a super simple console application, which does the same as step 1, except it writes a message to the console instead of throwing an exception. When I run that console app while executing the SpecFlow test, I see that data is sent to the console at the same time as SpecFlow advances to step 3. This tells me that the code for setting up the connection works, and that the notifications are sent before the SpecFlow test completes.

What am I missing here?.

Comment: Can you show the scenario in the feature file?

Comment: The async/await support in SpecFlow isn't that good at the moment. Specially with handling the SynchronizationContects. So my first guess would be, that you are hitting one of the problems.
But we are working on it to fix it. It should be done with the next minor version of SpecFlow 3.10.

Comment: @AndreasWillich Thanks for the hint. I tried to combine all the code in the 3 steps in one regular unit test, and that test worked. I think that we can conclude that the issue is with Specflow and not so much how I've written the test.